# Sticky Navigation Show with JQuery slideDown Slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, less

Code of **.JS** file

```
 $(document).scroll(function (){
        var menuheight= $('header').height();
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

      if (y>(menuheight))
       {

              $('.menu_nav_features').addClass('sticky');
       }

      else{
              $('.menu_nav_features').removeClass('sticky');
       }

 });
```

Code of **.css** `class` to be add on scroll down for specific height file

```
 .sticky{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
  }
```

This is my `Navigation Bar` code of **.less** file. ( for information )

```
   .menu_nav_features{
       width: 100%;
       height: 46px !important;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
       border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;

    .menu-features{
        margin-top: 0px;
        width: 1200px !important;
        list-style:none;
        margin-left: -35px;
        li{
            display: inline;
            .transition;
            a{  
                background: #f4f4f4;
                margin-right:-3px;
                display: inline-block;
                text-decoration: none;
                color:#444444;
                padding:0px 30px;
                line-height: 44px;
                .transition;
            }
            a:active, a:hover{
                color: #000;
                background: #fdfdfd;
            }
        }
        li:nth-child(2):hover .bf{
            .displayall;
            .transition;
        }
        .bf{
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 134px;
            padding-top: 7px;
            // top: 50px;
            .bf_btns{

                a{
                    display: block;
                    width: 238px !important;
                }
                a:last-child{
                    margin-top: 0px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

**Problem Statement :** When scroll bar height greater than my `Header` height then my Navigation  bar fix cause of `Sticky` `class`.It show immediately and i  want to show it slowly down or something like `slideDown` JQuery.I add `tranistion` to `Sticky` Class but nothing happened.

Comment: can you add the transition css to the code?

Comment: i did.`transition : all .2s linear;`  and tried other timing-function of transition

Comment: Problem is solved.I removed `Height` so now its working.Because of fix Height it create problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fix this problem with css

```
@keyframes scroll-down {
  from {transform: translate(0,100%)}
  to {transfrom: translate(0,0)}
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  animation-name: scroll-down;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}
```